# isomorphic to Galois group of the polynomial $(x-1)^2(x-3)^3(x-5)$

Tags: galois-theory

please some help to find the group that isomorphic to Galois group of the polynomial $f(x) = (x-1)^2(x-3)^3(x-5)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ splits over $\mathbb Q$, the Galois group of $f$ is the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb Q$ fixing $\mathbb Q$. What is that group?

**Edit:** A polynomial $f(x)$ is said to *split* over a field if it breaks into linear factors over that field.

For example, the polynomial $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ *does not split* over $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$ but it does split over $\mathbb Q(i)$, and $\mathbb C$. The polynomial $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)$ does not split over $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ or $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$, but it does split over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$. (Why?)

An *extension* of a field $F$ is just any larger field in which $F$ embeds. For example, $\mathbb C$ is an extension of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$ is an extension of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: i  have this answer (x^-2x+1)(x-3)(x^2-6x+3)(x-5) and the book answer   is z2 but i do not know how we get this ?

Comment: @user146264 What is the definition of the Galois group of a polynomial?

Comment: Let K be a field, let f(x) be a polynomial in K[x], and let F be a splitting field for f(x) over K. Then Gal(F/K) is called the Galois group of f(x) over K, or the Galois group of the equation f(x) = 0 over K.

Comment: Great! What is the splitting field in this case?

Comment: i do not know how i find it :(

Comment: What does it mean for a polynomial to split?

Comment: i am confuse between splitting and extension

Comment: Does my edit clear up the matter?

Comment: so is that mean when we split some equation of R that mean it will  reducible,and i think the answer of your question that The polynomial (x^2−2)(x^2−3) does not split over ℚ or ℚ(2√2) or ℚ(√3), but it does split over ℚ(√2,√3). (Why?),since  ℚ(√2,√3)is n contains both roots,is that correct,,is that correct the split of my polynomial are  (x-3)(x-3)(x-3)(x-1)(x-1)(x-5)?

Comment: i can tell u the answer of my book is Z2 ,i do like this (x^2-2x+1) is irreducible over Q the Golais extension of (x^2-2x+1) has at most 2!=2 element  also (x^2-6x+3) too has 2 elements ,,then is correct finally Z2 is isomorphic to Galois group of the polynomial (x−1)^2(x−3)^3(x−5)

Comment: thank u for your help  ,if  u would  check my comment i will be thankfull

Comment: Wait. $x^2-6x+3\neq(x-3)^2$.